# Google Pie chart text over chart color change

Tags: charts

[image]
I need to to change the % showing over pie chart text color. I used the following code

var options = {
          title: 'WGS Summary',
          width:650,
          height:425,
          is3D: true,
          legend: {position: 'top'},
          colors: ['#faf997','gray','orange','green'],
          legend: {textStyle: {color: '03c2f9'},
          pieSliceTextSlice:{color:'000000'}
          }
        };

Comment: pieSliceTextStyle not pieSliceTextSlice and the # is missing for the color.

Comment: Also it's not part of legend.